# Determining $dX_t$ for stochastic equations, and which of these are $\mathcal{F} $ - martingales?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I want to write down an expression for $dX_t$ for both:

i. $X_t=t^2W_t^2-2\int_0^t(sW_s^2+s^2)ds$; and

ii. $X_t=W_t^2-tW_t$

What is the process I would use for differentiating these stochastic equations?

Also how can I tell which of these are $\mathcal{F} $ - martingales on [0,T] where ${\mathcal{F_t}} $ is the natural filtration generated by $W_t$ ?

I believe we can assume that $\int_o^T\mathrm{E_p}[|W_t|^n]dt<\infty$ for all $n>0$

Please let me know if you have any advice or solution, would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use Ito's formulation to compute $dX_t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the first one; I leave the other one to you. First of all, it follows from the definition of $dX_t$ that

$$dX_t = d(t^2 W_t^2) -2 (t W_t^2+t^2) \, dt$$

i.e. we only have to calculate $d(t^2 W_t^2)$. By applying Itô's formula to $f(t,x) := t^2 \cdot x^2$ we see that

$$d(t^2 W_t^2) = 2 t^2 W_t \, dW_t + ( t^2 + 2t W_t^2) \, dt.$$

Hence,

$$dX_t = 2t^2 W_t \, dW_t - t^2 \, dt,$$

i.e.

$$X_t - X_0 = 2 \int_0^t s^2 W_s \, dW_s - \frac{t^3}{3}.$$

In order to decide whether $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale we recall that any stochastic integral of the form $\int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$ is a martingale. This means that

$$M_t := 2\int_0^t s^2 W_s \, dW_s$$

is a martingale. Since

$$X_t-X_0 - M_t = - \frac{t^3}{3}$$

is obviously not a martingale, this already implies that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is *not* a martingale.

**Remark** Note that the integrability condition $\int_0^T \mathbb{E}(|W_t|^n) \, dt<\infty$ is nothing "we can assume", we have to check it!

Comment: Thanks, I'm on (ii) now and have got my way to trying to check the integrability condition, I have got stuck though at the following point...

$\infty>\int_t^T E[\sigma_t^2]dt=E[(2W_t-t)^2]dt$

I was thinking of using the Ito isometry but the "$-t$" term is in the brackets! What should I now do to solve this? Expand the brackets? Still doesn't give me the right format though..

Thanks so much! @saz

Comment: @user146378 Which integrability condition do you want to check...? Basically, the point is that, as $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion, we know that $\mathbb{E}(|W_t|^n)<\infty$ for any $n \geq 1$ and $t \geq 0$. That's all you need in this case in order to prove the existence of the corresponding integrals.

Comment: okay thanks noted, but in order to determine if the equation for (ii) is an $\mathcal{F} $ - martingale, don't I need to try and figure this out? $\infty>\int_t^T E[\sigma_t^2]dt$

Cheers @saz

Comment: @user146378 What's $\sigma_t^2$...?

Comment: Sorry it's misleading, I used it as symbolising the Brownian motion component of the stochastic equation, and then squaring it. @saz

Comment: @user146378 Okay. Then you have to use that $$\mathbb{E}[(2W_t-t)^2] = 4\mathbb{E}(W_t^2)-4t \mathbb{E}(W_t)+t^2 = 4t-4t \cdot 0 + t^2 = 4t+t^2$$ which implies $$\int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(2W_t-t)^2] \, dt < \infty$$ for any $T \geq 0$.